# Split a String to another print when length is longer than 51, dont split a word (Lua)

Tags: string, lua, split

I'm trying to split a string if its longer than 51. I think my code is fine, but the Lua Demopage always says "attempt to call a nil value (field 'gfind')"

This is my code:

```
function _say_(text)
    local temptext = ""
    local tbl = {}
    for word in string.gfind(text, "%a+") do
        if string.len(temptext.." "..word) >= 52 then
            table.insert(tbl, temptext)
            temptext = word
        else
            temptext = temptext.." "..word
        end
    end
    table.insert(tbl, temptext)
    for i = 1, table.getn(tbl) do
        print(tbl[i])
    end
end
```

Comment: Because there is no `string.gfind` function in Lua standard library?

Comment: Try `string.gmatch` instead of `string.gfind`.

Comment: string.gmatch works, thanks!

Comment: gmatch was called gfind in Lua 5.0. In Lua 5.1, it is available as an alias for gmatch when compatibility mode is compiled in. In Lua 5.2 and later, only gmatch is available.